# EF Core Migrations with Postgres No database provider has been configured for this DbContext error

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql

I have two .Net 6 projects in my solution `App.Domain` and `App.Api`. `App.Domain` has EntityFramework and EF Design Nuget packages when I run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` in the `App.Domain` folder I get error `No database provider has been configured for this DbContext`

I'm pretty sure this is because I'm defining the database provider in my `App.Api` Startup.cs file but running the migration commands from the App.Domain folder. All the Google results suggest I move all of this into the `OnConfiguring` method in my `DbContext` class but this would remove my DI and break unit tests.

Is there a way past this or is it one way or the other?

**App.Api Startup.cs**

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
});
```

**DBContext**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("account");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make use of the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`. Here's a [tutorial](https://medium.com/oppr/net-core-using-entity-framework-core-in-a-separate-project-e8636f9dc9e5) that I think addresses your concern.